# Conversion from DateTime to Unix Epoch Time in Current Timezone

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin.android, android-calendar

I am using DateTime.Parse("01/18/2013") to get a DateTime object and then using the method below (passing all the parameters) to get an Unix Timestamp in millis.

```
long GetDateTimeMS(int yr, int month, int day, int hr, int min)

    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.TimeZone.Default);
        c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.DayOfMonth, day);
        c.Set(CalendarField.HourOfDay, hr);
        c.Set(CalendarField.Minute, min);
        c.Set(CalendarField.Month, month);
        c.Set(CalendarField.Year, yr);
                    return c.TimeInMillis;

    }
```

**Now when I use the below code to Create a Calendar Event in Android**

```
           //default timezone
            Java.Util.TimeZone zone = Java.Util.TimeZone.Default;
            var meetingDate = AndroidController.PoppedList[_estimateId].MeetingDate;
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


     values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart,
                 GetDateTimeMS(meetingDate.Year, meetingDate.Month, 
                                meetingDate.Day, 
                                  meetingDate.Hour, 
                                      meetingDate.Minute));

            meetingDate.AddHours(1);
            values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend,
                    GetDateTimeMS(meetingDate.Year,
                                meetingDate.Month, 
                                 meetingDate.Day, 
                                 meetingDate.Hour,
                                  meetingDate.Minute));

            values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, initTitle);

             values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId,_mSelectedCalendarId);

                values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, zone.DisplayName);



                Android.Net.Uri uri = _parentActivity.ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, values);
```

The event gets added to the calendar but with a wrong date. The date is advanced by one month in the calendar. The date I parsed is Friday January 18 2013 but the calendar event is created for Monday February 18 2013. Is this something related to my timezone? (I am already using the default timezone in java.util.timezone.default).

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your post to avoid all the extra linebreaks between the code, and use more appropriate indentation - the more readable your question is, the more likely it is that people will want to answer it.

Comment: Oops! I did make an edit there! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly the most immediate problem:

```
c.Set(CalendarField.Month, month);
```

My guess is that you're expecting 1 to mean January here - but `java.util.Calendar` uses 0-based months. You probably want:

```
c.Set(CalendarField.Month, month - 1);
```

There may *also* be time zone issues, but concentrate on the big ones first - being out by a whole month will almost never be a time zone issue.

Alternatively, to get the milliseconds since the unix epoch, you can stick to the .NET types - or even use my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) library. Using just `DateTime`:

```
private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch =
    new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

static long GetMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(int year, int month, int day,
                                          int hour, int minute)
{
    DateTime local = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0,
                                  DateTimeKind.Local);
    DateTime utc = local.ToUniversalTime();
    return (long) (utc - UnixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

Of course, if you're already using `DateTime.Parse`, you don't need to construct a new `DateTime` like this - you can just use the results of `DateTime.Parse`:

```
DateTime local = DateTime.Parse(..., DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, ...);
DateTime utc = local.ToUniversalTime();
long millis = (long) (utc - UnixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: My guess from all the language tags is that the OP wants to use C# for code for android. I am not sure android supports .NET types.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I'd be *very* surprised if Monodroid didn't support at least DateTime. My understanding is that Monodroid (now Xamarin.Android) is meant to be a "reasonably full" .NET stack. Note the use of `DateTime.Parse` in the first sentence in the question.

Comment: Wouldn't getting the Calendar instance for the default time zone provide me with the correct timestamp in millis (using the above code)?

Comment: @AniketSharma: Yes, but why introduce an extra conversion? Why not just stick to `DateTime`?

Comment: Using c.set(CalendarField.Month, month - 1) did the trick for me. Somehow the method you wrote below (GetMillisecondssinceUnixEpoch) was not giving the desired results when I was using its value in a Calendar Intent. Thanks!

Comment: @AniketSharma: It's possible that Monodroid's time zone support is broken... but it's hard to tell with just "was not giving the desired results" as we don't know what's wrong. I'd really suggest avoiding the Java date/time classes where possible - they're awful :(

Comment: @AniketSharma: "This broke up again" doesn't tell me anything about what actually happened, unfortunately. If you can give more details, I may be able to help you more.

Comment: The date is advanced by a month randomly(i.e some dates do, and some dates dont. On the other hand, using the (GetMillisecondssinceUnixEpoch) method was creating an event with the date 1/1/1970. I'll have a look again and get back to you. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why subtracting the local from utc of the same date give us the milliseconds since epoch? We need to subtract the UnixEpoch from the utc, right?

Comment: @nohros: Indeed. I should be subtracting `UnixEpoch` instead of `local`. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

A common gotcha of the calendar months is that Janurary is 0 not 1.

BTW If you don't set the milli-seconds, it will be whatever the current millis are.  You might want to set it to zero to avoid confusion.